# JQuery drop down list filter

Tags: jquery, dom-manipulation

I have first drop down list `ddl1` which contains these values:

- Car
- Van

and the second drop down list `ddl2` contains:

- Car Honda
- Car BMW
- Van Golf

I need a script that filters the second ddl for example when I choose `Car`, the second ddl should only show these two fields:

Car Honda
 - Car BMW

My code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function Filter(){
    var names = $('#typeCar option').clone();
    $('#Type').change(function(){
        var val = $(this).val();
        $('#typeCar').empty();
        names.filter(function(idx, el){
            return val === 'ALL' || $(el).text().indexOf(val) >= 0;
        }).appendTo('#typeCar');
    });
}
</script>
```

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
    function Filter() {
        var names = $('#Insurance option').clone();

        $('#Type').change(function () {
            var val = $(this).val();
            $('#Insurance').empty();
            names.filter(function (idx, el) {
                return val === 'ALL' || $(el).text().indexOf(val) >= 0;
            }).appendTo('#Insurance');
        });

    }
</script>

Comment: @sally: I edited it into your question, it's a lot more readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you will want something like this:

Each List Item value in the second list should start with the same value of the item in the first list. This is so it can be filtered by the value of the first.

EDIT:

Items in drop downs.

List 1:

```
Car     -Value = 001
Truck   -Value = 002
Van     -Value = 003
```

List 2:

```
Car option 1 - Value = 001001
Car option 2 - Value = 001002
Car option 3 - Value = 001003
Truck   option 1 - Value = 002001
Truck   option 2 - Value = 002002
Truck   option 3 - Value = 002003
Van     option 1 - Value = 003001
Van     option 2 - Value = 003002
Van     option 3 - Value = 003003
```

Javascript:

```
<script>

    //Array to hold original subTypes
    var _SubTypes = new Array();

    $(document).ready(
                      function()
              {
                //Store the sub types
                StoreSubTypes();

                //Set up company Type on Change
                $("#comp_type").change(CompanyTypeOnChange);
                      }
                     );

    //Function to Store Initial List of Sub Types
    function StoreSubTypes()
    {
        $("#comp_subtype option").each(
                               function(index, option)
                           {
                            //Store the option
                            _SubTypes[index] = option;
                           }
                          );
    }

    //Function to Filter Company Sub Types and Hide various fields
    function CompanyTypeOnChange()
    {
        //Filter the Sub TYpes
        FilterSubTypes();
    }

    //Filters the company sub types drop down
    function FilterSubTypes()
    {
        //Get the value of the selected Company Type
        var compType = $("#comp_type").val();

        //Remove all Sub Type Items
        $("#comp_subtype option").remove();


        //Add the related items back to the list
        $.each(_SubTypes, function(index, value)
                  {
                    //Get the current option
                    var option = _SubTypes[index];

                    //Get the first 3 characters of the value - this is the same as the compType if related
                    var subTypeIdentifier = option.value.substring(0,3);

                    //Add the option to the list if its valid for the compType
                    if(subTypeIdentifier==compType)
                    {       
                        $("#comp_subtype").append(option);
                    }

                    //Add the --None-- option
                    if (option.value=="")
                    {
                        $("#comp_subtype").append(option);
                    }
                  }
                  );
    }


    </script>
```

Comment: when try to run it gives me an error on javascript object expected

Comment: <select id="comp_type">
     <option selected="true" >Car Loan</option>
    <option>Truck Loan</option>
    <option>Taxi Loan</option>
  
</select>


<select id="comp_subtype">
    <option>Car Insurance1</option>
    <option>Car Insurance2</option>
    <option>Truck Insurance1</option>
    <option>Truck Insurance2</option>
    <option>Taxi Insurance1</option>
</select>

this my code

Comment: @Sally - I have not written the code using the names of your controls etc, Its more of an example to show you how to do it. If you read through the comments it should give you an idea of how to acheive what you are looking for. Without seeing the full code for your page, and the line number the error is on its hard to see where the problem is

Comment: @Sally, I have added list items to my answer as an example of the values for the list items

Comment: of course i changed the names of the variables but gives a runtime error in javascript

Comment: it gives me object expected any javascript librabry is needed here ?

Comment: only jQuery is required. I thought you had that referenced already though?

Comment: the error javascript worked but what should i fill in HideShowFields()

Comment: Ah, you can remove the reference to hide show fields, I thought I removed all referecnes to it but its not required. The bespoke I wrote also removed fields from the page based on what was selected so you do not need to worry about that bit.

Comment: just one more thing when i choose the first option for the first time it doesn't filter values why ? thanks

Comment: Do you mean if you select the first item in the list that is already selected then nothing happens? You could try calling CompanyTypeOnChange at the end of the document.ready function so the second list is filtered straight away

Comment: I tried calling CompanyTypeOnChange  at the end of document.ready it worked thanks a lot